# How do I create animation for google adwords?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif, google

I have created an ad campaign for Google Adwords in Photoshop and am now saving the files as .gif but I cant get my file sizes to under 150kb while keeping the image quality.

What are my options here?

I have looked into other ways to shrink .gif file size while keeping the quality, saving my photoshop files to .html, or recreating the ads in Google Web Designer.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the .gif ? Would help to know the length, the amount of colors, etc to give any sort of suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Use [EZGIF](https://ezgif.com/optimize) to compress your GIF files without loosing **much of it's quality**.

It has various methods of compressing GIF's like Color Reduction, Drop Frames, Lossy Compression, etc. You can also select the compression level if you are getting a really bad result.

I would recommend you to select **Lossy compression** with **35%** compression level as it worked best most of the time for me.

Answer (score 0):

150kb gives you a fair bit of scope for animated gifs.

If you have a lot of animation in a timeline and frame tweening it will bloat file size.

Heaps on google:
https://www.google.com.au/search?q=reduce+filesize+of+gif+photoshop&oq=reduce+filesize+of+gif+photoshop&aqs=chrome..69i57.8215j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8